# Message Translation Between Systems

Tags: translation, messaging

I find that most of my work involves creating shims so that different systems can communicate with each other.

Is there any software solutions that handle this.  I don't want to make my own.

For example if we received a message like { a: 'abc', b: 1 } from System1, we might want to send { a: f('abc'), c: 'System1'} to System2.

Know of anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

We use the JMS [`MapMessage`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html) to communicate between apps.  Conceptually this is like passing around a HashMap between applications.

We define a set of core keys that apps must specify (message type, date, etc).

Then per message type, we define add'l keys.

It's a simple way to do interapp communication.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite the same.  It doesn't work for applications that are outside of your control, nor provide translation between systems independent of those systems.